# Create email notification request link function

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I created a function to create link but am encountering errors when creating a variable, tried declaring but declare would have an error

```
create or replace FUNCTION CREATE_REQUEST_LINK(request_id IN VARCHAR2, task_id IN VARCHAR2)

RETURN VARCHAR2 AS 

request_link varchar2(100);

BEGIN
first_half varchar2 := apex_mail.get_instance_url;
second_half varchar2 := 'f?p=&APP_ID.:&APP_PAGE.:&APP_SESSION.::::';

request_link := first_half + second_half;

  RETURN request_link;
END WF_CREATE_REQUEST_LINK;
```

It was returning on Line 8 and 9

Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "VARCHAR2" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ; The symbol "." was substituted for "VARCHAR2" to continue.

Is there a way to fix. I'm kinda new to Oracle Apex

Additional question, am I right in creating the 2nd half, the plan is that the $APP_SESSION. after clicking the link will be changed into the session id after logging in.

Answer (score 1):

- You seem to want to declare two local variables `first_half` and `second_half`.  Variable declarations need to happen in the declaration section of a block.
- When you declare a `varchar2` variable, you need to provide a length.  I'll guess that you want both local variables to have a maximum length of 100.
- The string concatenation operator is `||` not `+`

So you probably want something like

```
create or replace FUNCTION CREATE_REQUEST_LINK(
    request_id IN VARCHAR2, 
    task_id IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2 
AS 
  request_link varchar2(100);
  first_half   varchar2(100) := apex_mail.get_instance_url;
  second_half  varchar2(100) := 'f?p=&APP_ID.:&APP_PAGE.:&APP_SESSION.::::';
BEGIN
  request_link := first_half || second_half;

  RETURN request_link;
END WF_CREATE_REQUEST_LINK;
```

Comment: Maybe just setting REQUEST_LINK to VARCHAR2(**200**)? (you know, concatenating two 100 characters long strings into a 100 characters long variable won't work) (yes, I know, 100 is probably too much for FIRST and SECOND halves).

Comment: @Littlefoot - Reasonable.  I doubt that either half would actually exceed 50 characters but that will depend on what the original poster's instance name looks like.  Ideally, you'd work out the actual lengths of things and set the limits appropriately.